# How do you fix this pricing model loophole?

Tags: pricing

Suppose a SaaS product charges per project, whereby the first project you own is free. Ideally, users would open up a project and invite a few members to work on it. If more projects are needed, the same user within a team would open up another project which then is charged for.

[image: Ideal Scenario]

With above restrictions, nothing would stop a team from rotating project ownership to make use of the free project per user, effectively gaining `n` free projects for a team size of `n` members.

[image: Loophole exploited]

What criteria could you use to detect such a scenario and how could you fix it?

**Things I've thought of**

- You can only be member of at most one "free" project. That's hard to enforce because you can't really label any project "free" or "paid" if you charge for `n-1` projects. Which one is the "free" one?
- Reserve certain permissions for the project owner only. That's not feasible either because in the context of large organisations, there should probably be multiple members with full access.

Comment: "Which one is the "free" one?"  The first one established in time, perhaps wherefore with the lowest ID.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal concerns or business strategies. It is not about a software engineering problem.

Comment: @amon It's about the right model design to prevent the situation above. Neither the pricing strategy nor legal matters are subject of the question. Please leave it open.

Comment: @DoubleM Ironic how the answer you accepted was all about pricing strategy and legal matters.

Comment: @R.Schmitz it was a comment on this answer by its author that led me to the right solution. The relevant part is "you could allow individuals to use your service with just one member".

Comment: @DoubleM I don't understand, is your point that it's not about legal matters, _only_ about pricing strategy? Don't get me wrong, I would have been _very_ surprised if somebody were able to solve your issue through _software engineering_, that just seems impossible.

Comment: @R.Schmitz I can see how it might be pushing the boundaries. From a pure model design perspective, I was looking for a mechanism to prevent the `n members` = `n free projects` flaw to be infinitely exploitable. I was not seeking advice on the pricing concept or looking for any legal solutions. Putting an upper boundary on `n` solves the problem well. Which stackexchange site would you rather put this on, if any?

Comment: @DoubleM I see where your confusion comes from - the implementation would be _done with code_. The thing is that the code only models the business decisions. The business says "we want 3 licenses per group" and then the code only has to reflect that (and it wouldn't be particularly _difficult_ to code). If the business has to decide on selling pants vs selling tooth brushes, the decision will also need to be programmed for the web shop, but that doesn't make it a decision for the lead programmer.

Comment: Your question might fit _better_ in project management or economics, but that also doesn't fit 100%. We don't have the right site yet. Currently we have a decent question with a decent answer in an inappropriate place, not really worth the effort to change that now.

Comment: @R.Schmitz I understand. To be honest, I wasn't sure if this question would fit but tried my best to put it into SE context. Sorry if it doesn't exactly meet the regulations. Got the answer I was looking for though, stackexchange rules.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: IMHO this question is about how to structure features in a system to allow a better pricing model - this is a combination of softwareengineering and economics, I don't see this necessarily as contrary things. I think there is enough "SE" in the question to make it on-topic here.

Comment: @amon: my last comment is for you as well.

Comment: @DocBrown I'm still of the opinion that - given a sufficiently large company of course - this decision would be made in one room with sales and marketing people, plus possibly one engineer to make sure it's technically possible. The done decision would then be given to the next room full of software engineers, who have to implement it _as it is_. I don't expect to ever have to answer this question in my job as programmer. However, I also think this is the most fitting stackexchange site for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the model to "one free project per organization". Apparantly that is what you really want, and the identity of organizations can be checked to some degree of certainty by things like tax ID, official website/URL and similar properties.

For individuals who don't want to register to your service as an organization, you may offer to use your service with just one member (themselves) per project, or with a very limited number of users per project. It depends on the precise nature of the service how useful or sensible this is.

Moreover, you should primarily protect yourself against abuse of the pricing model legally, by writing this into your "terms of service". Technical measures should be only supporting this. So even if someone finds a technical loophole, they will probably hesitate to make use of it because of the risk of getting excluded from your service or getting sued.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - that would basically require every user who wants to try the product to have access to details of an organization which is a legal entity, or at least has a website, right? That would probably impose a higher barrier for people to get started, or even be impossible to achieve for individuals. I was hoping to grant one project per account, but with some kind of lock that would snap in above scenario. I do appreciate your advice about the ToS!

Comment: @DoubleM: you could allow individuals to use your service with just one member (themselves) per project, and allow teams only when registered as an organization. However, it is hard to give you a better advice without knowing more about the precise nature of the service, how interesting/ important/useful it is to individuals, teams and/or organizations.

Comment: Limiting the amount of members on a free project might just nail it. If you allow a maximum of e.g. five members, a closed group can never go beyond five free projects.

Answer (score 3):

First of all maybe it's nothing wrong with your pricing model.

Considering that you are offering a "free trial" like every other SaaS out there, I don't see anything wrong. Any SaaS can have this issue where they could theoretically create infinte accounts just to get unlimited free service.

That's not how business is done with this type of thinking. Don't think about this from a mathematical point of view. think of it from a social point of view. Add different kind of constraints to keep the good customers in.

Constraints similar to what @Doc Brown said. Ask them for CC data, or ask them to give you a call (many ask for a call to give the customer a quote), ask for identitification (company details or whatever), ask them to verify the phone number and send them a code for a free project. In my opinion you should put "social/marketing" type of constraints for this. You can even put some kind of firewall and monitor abuse of the free part of your service.

There are plenty SaaS platforms out there from which you can get some inspiration. Steal the ideas from the big SaaS platforms out there. Their marketing team surely knows many things, tried and tested strategies.

Comment: That is certainly another perspective to look at it. I'll let it sink in, thank you.